# Columns Not Dropping in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two functions.

The first one displays the percentage of null-values per column in a dataframe:

```
def n_percent_nulls(self):
    global percent_null
    percent_null = self.isnull().sum() *100 / self.shape[0]
    return percent_null
```

The second one calculates which columns have over 40% null-values and asks the user, one by one, if she/he wants to drop the columns:

```
def drop_n_percent_nulls(self):
    df_columns = list(self.columns)
    s = pd.Series(percent_null, index=[x for x in df_columns])
    for k, v in s.items():
        if v > (40):
            ask_user("\n{0} has over 40% null values, Would you like to drop it? (yes/no)\n".format(k))
            if ask_user in yes_values:
                self.df = self.df.drop(self.columns[k], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

When I call the function `df.drop_n_percent_nulls()` in the `main()` function of the program it will correctly present the column, accept user input, and cast no errors. However, when I present the dataframe later in the program, the columns that were supposed to be dropped still exist.

Comment: When you use inplace in drop, you don't need to assign the dataframe to a variable again

Comment: If you use `inplace=True`, the method returns `None`. It is not "you don't need", but you *musn't*

Comment: Is `ask_user` a function? You should probably be assigning its return value to a variable and checking if that is in `yes_values`...

Comment: Thanks guys. Removing the inplace parameter fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the line `self.df = self.df.drop(self.columns[k], axis=1, inplace=True)`. Since the drop is inplace, doing `self.df.drop(self.columns[k], axis=1, inplace=True)` should be sufficient. When doing inplace, the return-value of the drop-operation is `None` (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the `if ask_user in yes_values:` is not evaluated to `True` because if it does, the `self.df` would be `None` (reason below).

That's the problem, but once you get that part right you'd find the below issue:

---

You should remove `inplace=True` in the last row of the second function:

```
if ask_user in yes_values:
    self.df = self.df.drop(self.columns[k], axis=1)
```

because the return value of `inplace=True` functions in pandas is `None`.

Or you don't assign the output of the function back to `self.df`:

```
if ask_user in yes_values:
    self.df.drop(self.columns[k], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This should work too.

Comment: Looks like a mistake in the question; `ask_user` seems like a function, but the user is checking if the function itself is in `yes_values`.

Comment: Oh that’s why the block after the if clause never executes:/ I’d use input function and store the answer in ask_user variable or something instead